# How to perform binary search on a preordered DataFrame?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame sorted by a column; and I need to perform a binary search to find the first value equal or greater than a specified value.
Is there any way to do this efficiently in Spark?

Comment: What do you mean by 'Efficiently'. With what do you want to compare efficiency?

Comment: @KavinduRavishka with a straightforward approach of iterating over every single row. It has to be binary search instead.

Comment: Binary search is always efficient rather than iterating in these type of searches. You can use binary search and also even faster by using indexing (index not equal row number) along with binary search. You must have heard of indexing since you are working with databases.

Comment: @KavinduRavishka the question is, **how** do I make it use binary search?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible. It is a bulk processing framework in which JOINs play a prevalent role using different techniques.

No where in the docs have I seen or read elsewhere of a binary search. That I did at University with in-memory Pascal structures.

Comment: Too bad. Because there aren't any technical reasons why it can't be possible.

Comment: But it is a framework that offers services.